# Travis CI skipping SonarQube analysis

Tags: sonarqube, travis-ci

I'm trying to configure SonarQube analysis in a github project. I've followed the official travis ci documentation but SonarQube analysis is not performed.

I'm getting the following message: "Skipping SonarQube Scan because it is not running in a secure environment"

pull request link: https://github.com/zakshya/cronos/pull/4

Full build log: https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/216125526/log.txt

Does some one encountered this problem ?
I'm i missing some config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official documentation of the SonarQube Travis Add-on](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarqube/) about analysing pull requests:

> For security reasons, this advanced feature 
>   *[i.e. pull request analysis]* 
>   works only for internal pull requests. In other words, pull requests
>   built from forks won’t be inspected.